# Find global maximum of an equation using python

Tags: python-3.x, max, sympy, maximize

I am trying to write some codes to find the global maximum of an equation, e.g. `f = -x**4`.

Here is what I have got at the moment.

```
import sympy
x = sympy.symbols('x')
f = -x**4
df = sympy.diff(f,x)
ans = sympy.solve(df,x)
```

Then I am stuck. How should I substitute `ans` back into `f`, and how would I know if that would be the maximum, but not the minimum or a saddle point?

Comment: The answer to the second question is [the second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test). For a function of one variable, check whether its second derivative at the critical point is strictly negative.

Comment: I understand second derivative test should be used, however, it would still give ```f''(0) = 0```, which is inconclusive.

Comment: Actually yes, the second derivative test may be inconclusive. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second-derivative_test_(single_variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for the global maximum and nothing else, then there is already a function for that. See the following:

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
f = -x**4
print(maximum(f, x))  # 0
```

If you want more information such as the x value that gives that max or maybe local maxima, you'll have to do more manual work. In the following, I find the critical values as you have done above and then I show the values as those critical points.

```py
diff_f = diff(f, x)
critical_points = solve(diff_f, x)
print(critical_points)  # x values
for point in critical_points:
    print(f.subs(x, point))  # f(x) values
```

This can be extended to include the second derivative test as follows:

```py
d_f = diff(f, x)
dd_f = diff(f, x, 2)
critical_points = solve(d_f, x)
for point in critical_points:
    if dd_f.subs(x, point) < 0:
        print(f"Local maximum at x={point} with f({point})={f.subs(x, point)}")
    elif dd_f.subs(x, point) > 0:
        print(f"Local minimum at x={point} with f({point})={f.subs(x, point)}")
    else:
        print(f"Inconclusive at x={point} with f({point})={f.subs(x, point)}")
```

To find the global max, you would need to take all your critical points and evaluate the function at those points. Then pick the max from those.

```py
outputs = [f.subs(x, point) for point in critical_points]
optimal_x = [point for point in critical_points if f.subs(x, point) == max(outputs)]

print(f"The values x={optimal_x} all produce a global max at f(x)={max(outputs)}")
```

The above should work for most elementary functions. Apologies for the inconsistent naming of variables.

If you are struggling with simple things like substitution, I suggest going through [the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html) for an hour or two.